# Remove Authorization from request headers in particular http call

Tags: angular

Interceptor -

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService, private router: Router) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.showLoader();
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`, 
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.hideLoader();
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.hideLoader();
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigate(['../auth']);
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

Service -

```
 getList() {
    return this.commonHttpService.get(`common/List`);  
  }
```

TS API call -

```
 List() {
    this.Service.getList()
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.Data = res.body.data;
      });
  }
```

I want to remove the **Authorization** from request headers when I call this API.

How can we do that? Searched many answers on stackoverflow but nothing worked.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the interceptor you can have a list of Uris that you won't add the Auth header.

```
if (unauthorizedUris.every(x => x !== request.url))
    request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`, 
    }});
```